# Sorting DataFrame to show combination of items with count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
         Created at       Items     Qty
0   2020-12-22 13:06:00     A        3
0   2020-12-22 13:06:00     B        1
1   2020-12-22 13:32:00     C        1
2   2020-12-22 14:34:00     D        1
2   2020-12-22 14:34:00     E        1
3   2020-12-31 21:14:00     D        1
3   2020-12-31 21:14:00     F        1
3   2020-12-31 21:14:00     G        1
4   2020-12-31 21:34:00     D        1
4   2020-12-31 21:34:00     C        2
5   2020-12-31 22:12:00     A        1
5   2020-12-31 22:12:00     B        2
5   2020-12-31 22:12:00     G        2
5   2020-12-31 22:12:00     F        1
```

I need to sort it in a way to show the combination of items within same index, and their count, as follows:

```
    Item comb        Count
0    A & B            2
1    C                1
2    D & E            1
3    D & F            1
4    D & G            1
5    F & G            2
6    C & D            1
7    A & G            1
8    B & G            1
10   A & F            1
11   B & F            1
```

For example, in the above result, Item Comb in the first row was count as 2 because it appeared as a combination in the dataframe index 0 and index 5.
Row 2 did not have any other item with it so it appeared as a separate item and counted as 1.
Combination are always showing for Example A&B, and counts A&B and B&A as A&B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate [**`itertools.combinations`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) within groups and [**`explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the resulting combination lists. Then sort each combination (so `G-F` matches `F-G`) and get their [**`value_counts`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```py
from itertools import combinations as nCr

comb = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda g:
    list(nCr(g.Items, 2)) if g.Items.size > 1 else [(g.Items.iloc[0],)]
)

comb = comb.explode().apply(sorted).apply(tuple).value_counts()

# (A, B)    2
# (F, G)    2
# (D, G)    1
# (C, D)    1
# (B, F)    1
# (D, E)    1
# (A, G)    1
# (B, G)    1
# (A, F)    1
# (D, F)    1
# (C,)      1
# dtype: int64
```